# $(':checkbox') or $('input[type="checkbox"]')

Tags: javascript, jquery

Which method is the best to select checkbox using jquery and why?

```
$('input:checkbox'); // 1
$('input[type="checkbox"]'); // 2
```

Comment: None is "best". Although, second one is faster

Comment: second it's the fastest by a lot http://jsperf.com/checkbox-selector

Comment: @JuanC. But does it make it "better"? That depends how we could understand "best". I mean someone could argue that the best regarding readibility is `:checkbox`. Anyway, if OP has to select thousand checkboxes at once, something is wrong somewhere else

Comment: @A.Wolff +1 for pointing out pure consideration of speed may not be necessary when designing a web page normally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, according to the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/):

> Because :checkbox is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using :checkbox cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll()
>   method. For better performance in modern browsers, use
>   [type="checkbox"] instead.